# Who's the President of the USA (in Supergirl)?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, supergirl, supergirl-2015

It has been referenced several times throughout Supergirl that the President is a woman.

I'm wondering who is the President of the US is, and whether there's a particular reason for this aspect being different from Earth-1 (if you consider Barry Allen's Flash on The Flash as Earth-1)?

**Who is she** and **is there any indication that she'll play a more important role in later episodes?**

Answer (score 2):

Jokingly, the film's showrunners indicated [in an interview](http://www.ew.com/article/2016/03/24/wonder-woman-supergirl-lynda-carter) that Lynda Carter (of 1975 "[Wonder Woman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wonder_Woman_(TV_series))" fame) will be the President of the USA in the Supergirl-verse

> “We had the perfect role for Lynda Carter,” Berlanti said of the
>   Wonder Woman alum. “We couldn’t work out her schedule. Next year.”
>
> Interjected Kreisberg: “We’re going to do it, we’ll just do it next
>   year,” which prompted Berlanti to reveal her potential role: **“All
>   right, she’s the female president of the United States.”**

They refused to be drawn on whether she'll simply be cameoing or reprising her role as Wonder Woman.